# Error using FEM package

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm getting the following error:

> NDSolveValue: The FEMStiffnessElements operator failed.

I looked for this error in FEM documentation and did not find anything. I'm using Mathematica 12.

It follows my code:

```
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

G = 6.894745 10^9;

E1 = 26.25 G; E2 = 1.49 G; G12 = 
 1.04 G; nu12 = 0.28; nu21 = (E2*nu12)/E1;

t = 0.0050 .0254;
Son = {{1/E1, -nu12/E1, 0}, {-nu21/E2, 1/E2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/G12}}; Qon =
  Inverse[Son];

Q11 = Qon[[1, 1]]; Q12 = Qon[[1, 2]]; Q22 = Qon[[2, 2]]; Q66 = 
 Qon[[3, 3]];

U1 = (3 Q11 + 3 Q22 + 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8; U2 = (Q11 - Q22)/
  2; U3 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U4 = (Q11 + Q22 + 6 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U5 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8;

alpha = 0 (\[Pi]/180);
a = 1; b = 1; d = a Cos[alpha] + b Sin[alpha];
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
u0 = 0.01;

angle1 = 10; angle0 = 0;
angles = {{angle0, angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, angle1}};

num = Dimensions[angles][[1]]; h = num*t; pos = Table[0, num + 1]; 
pos[[1]] = -h/2;
For[i = 2, i <= num + 1, i++, pos[[i]] = pos[[i - 1]] + t];

\[Xi]A = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]B = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]D = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

For[i = 1, i <= num, i++,

  T0 = angles[[i, 1]] ;
  T1 = angles[[i, 2]] ;
  func[s_] := 
   Simplify@((2.0/d) (T1 - T0) Sqrt[(s - d/2)^2] + T0) (\[Pi]/180);
  theta[x_, y_] := alpha + func[x Cos[alpha] + y Sin[alpha]];

  zA = pos[[i + 1]] - pos[[i]]; zB = pos[[i + 1]]^2 - pos[[i]]^2; 
  zD = pos[[i + 1]]^3 - pos[[i]]^3;

  V1 = Cos[2 theta[x, y]]; V2 = Sin[2 theta[x, y]]; 
  V3 = Cos[4 theta[x, y]]; V4 = Sin[4 theta[x, y]];

  \[Xi]a = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zA;
  \[Xi]b = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zB;
  \[Xi]d = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zD;

  \[Xi]A = \[Xi]A + \[Xi]a;
  \[Xi]B = \[Xi]B + \[Xi]b;
  \[Xi]D = \[Xi]D + \[Xi]d;

  ];

mU = {
   {U1, U2, 0, U3, 0},
   {U4, 0, 0, -U3, 0},
   {U1, -U2, 0, U3, 0},
   {0, 0, U2/2, 0, U3},
   {0, 0, U2/2, 0, -U3},
   {U5, 0, 0, -U3, 0}
   };

mA = mU.\[Xi]A; mB = (mU.\[Xi]B)/2; mD = (mU.\[Xi]D)/3;

A11[x_, y_] = mA[[1]]; A12[x_, y_] = mA[[2]]; A16[x_, y_] = mA[[4]]; 
A22[x_, y_] = mA[[3]]; A26[x_, y_] = mA[[5]]; A66[x_, y_] = mA[[6]]; 
D11[x_, y_] = mD[[1]]; D12[x_, y_] = mD[[2]]; D16[x_, y_] = mD[[4]]; 
D22[x_, y_] = mD[[3]]; D26[x_, y_] = mD[[5]]; D66[x_, y_] = mD[[6]];

Nx[x_, y_] = 
  A11[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A12[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A16[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

Ny[x_, y_] = 
  A12[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A22[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A26[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

Nxy[x_, y_] = 
  A16[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A26[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A66[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

PDEs =
  {
   D[Nx[x, y], {x, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {y, 1}], 
   D[Ny[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {x, 1}]
   };

gammaD =
  {
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == 0],
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == b]
   };

omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];

{U, V} =
  NDSolveValue[{
    PDEs == {0, 0},
    gammaD,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == a/2]
    },
   {u, v}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh
   ];
```

Basically I'm trying to solve a 2D elasticity (a plate under a prescribed displacement) problem above. I already solved it considering a 1D variation of the theta function e all went well. Now I need to solve considering a 2D variation of the theta function `theta[x,y]`. What I changed it was the function `theta`, but I'm getting this error.

Does anyone knows the reason of this error and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

It using `alpha = 0 (\[Pi]/180)` my code runs like a charm. But when I set `45 (\[Pi]/180)` I get division-by-zero.

Comment: Okay, when I evaluate your code in a fresh _Mathematica_ kernel, I get already a couple of division-by-zero errors before `NDSolveValue` does anything. Maybe it would be a good idea to resolve these first?

Comment: I also tried it and get same error message as Henrik. Division by zero. It is good to look at ALL the error messages in the console and not  just at the last error at the end, because the earlier error messages most likely is what caused the last one you saw.

Comment: Really, I'm getting division-by-zero as well, I thought could be due to FEM error. I can't understand that division-by-zero error in my code. Could you help me in that issue? I updated my code due to some typo right now and the error still happening. I noticed that using `alpha = 0 (\[Pi]/180)` my code runs properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a precision issue. `Rationalize` all your numbers and use

```
PDEs = FullSimplify[PDEs];
```

on the resulting PDE. Then it will work.

**Code Dump**

This works for 12.1:

```
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

G = Rationalize[6.894745 10^9]
E1 = Rationalize[26.25 G]; E2 = Rationalize[1.49 G]; G12 = 
 Rationalize[1.04 G]; nu12 = Rationalize[0.28]; nu21 = (E2*nu12)/E1;

t = Rationalize[0.0050 .0254];
Son = {{1/E1, -nu12/E1, 0}, {-nu21/E2, 1/E2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/G12}};

Qon = Inverse[Son];
Q11 = Qon[[1, 1]]; Q12 = Qon[[1, 2]]; Q22 = Qon[[2, 2]]; Q66 = 
 Qon[[3, 3]];

U1 = (3 Q11 + 3 Q22 + 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8; U2 = (Q11 - Q22)/
  2; U3 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U4 = (Q11 + Q22 + 6 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U5 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8;

alpha = 45 (\[Pi]/180);
a = 1; b = 1; d = a Cos[alpha] + b Sin[alpha];
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
u0 = Rationalize[0.01];
angle1 = 10; angle0 = 0;
angles = {{angle0, angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, angle1}};

num = Dimensions[angles][[1]]; h = num*t; pos = Table[0, num + 1];
pos[[1]] = -h/2;
For[i = 2, i <= num + 1, i++, pos[[i]] = pos[[i - 1]] + t];

\[Xi]A = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]B = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]D = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, T0 = angles[[i, 1]];
  T1 = angles[[i, 2]];
  func[s_] := 
   Simplify@((2/d) (T1 - T0) Sqrt[(s - d/2)^2] + T0) (\[Pi]/180);
  theta[x_, y_] := alpha + func[x Cos[alpha] + y Sin[alpha]];
  zA = pos[[i + 1]] - pos[[i]];
  zB = pos[[i + 1]]^2 - pos[[i]]^2;
  zD = pos[[i + 1]]^3 - pos[[i]]^3;
  V1 = Cos[2 theta[x, y]]; V2 = Sin[2 theta[x, y]];
  V3 = Cos[4 theta[x, y]]; V4 = Sin[4 theta[x, y]];
  \[Xi]a = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zA;
  \[Xi]b = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zB;
  \[Xi]d = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zD;
  \[Xi]A = \[Xi]A + \[Xi]a;
  \[Xi]B = \[Xi]B + \[Xi]b;
  \[Xi]D = \[Xi]D + \[Xi]d;];
mU = {{U1, U2, 0, U3, 0}, {U4, 0, 0, -U3, 0}, {U1, -U2, 0, U3, 0}, {0,
     0, U2/2, 0, U3}, {0, 0, U2/2, 0, -U3}, {U5, 0, 0, -U3, 0}};

mA = mU.\[Xi]A; mB = (mU.\[Xi]B)/2; mD = (mU.\[Xi]D)/3;
A11[x_, y_] = mA[[1]]; A12[x_, y_] = mA[[2]]; A16[x_, y_] = mA[[4]];
A22[x_, y_] = mA[[3]]; A26[x_, y_] = mA[[5]]; A66[x_, y_] = mA[[6]];
D11[x_, y_] = mD[[1]]; D12[x_, y_] = mD[[2]]; D16[x_, y_] = mD[[4]];
D22[x_, y_] = mD[[3]]; D26[x_, y_] = mD[[5]]; D66[x_, y_] = mD[[6]];

Nx[x_, y_] = 
  A11[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A12[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A16[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);
Ny[x_, y_] = 
  A12[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A22[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A26[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

Nxy[x_, y_] = 
  A16[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A26[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A66[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

PDEs = {D[Nx[x, y], {x, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {y, 1}], 
   D[Ny[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {x, 1}]};

gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == b]};
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];

PDEs = FullSimplify[PDEs];

{U, V} = NDSolveValue[{PDEs == {0, 0}, gammaD, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == a/2]}, {u, 
    v}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

Comment: I did it and it is not working yet. I'm getting division-by-zero. Did you change my code and run it? Only the `FullSimplify[PDEs]` took 30+ min in my PC. Is it that time of computing normal?

Comment: @DiegoMagela Make sure the PDE you put into `FullSimplify` are **all** rational numbers. In other words no reals!

Comment: @DiegoMagela I dumped the code in the post.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you. For others angles, for instance 35 degree, it is taking too long to evaluate, while using your code for 45 degree is very fast. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @DiegoMagela, in that case the equations can not be simplified as easy as in the 45 case. Try `Simplify` in stead of `FullSimplify` and see if that also helps.