# High peaks of FEM solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Following [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219452/error-using-fem-package/219482?noredirect=1#comment559051_219482) and [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21) answered, I changed the BCs of the initial problem. The code following bellow.

```
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

G = Rationalize[6.894745 10^9]
E1 = Rationalize[26.25 G]; E2 = Rationalize[1.49 G]; G12 = 
 Rationalize[1.04 G]; nu12 = Rationalize[0.28]; nu21 = (E2*nu12)/E1;

t = Rationalize[0.0050 .0254];
Son = {{1/E1, -nu12/E1, 0}, {-nu21/E2, 1/E2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/G12}};

Qon = Inverse[Son];
Q11 = Qon[[1, 1]]; Q12 = Qon[[1, 2]]; Q22 = Qon[[2, 2]]; Q66 = 
 Qon[[3, 3]];

U1 = (3 Q11 + 3 Q22 + 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8; U2 = (Q11 - Q22)/
  2; U3 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U4 = (Q11 + Q22 + 6 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U5 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8;

alpha = 45 (\[Pi]/180);
a = 1; b = 1; d = a Cos[alpha] + b Sin[alpha];
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
u0 = Rationalize[0.01];
angle1 = 10; angle0 = 0;
angles = {{angle0, angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, angle1}};

num = Dimensions[angles][[1]]; h = num*t; pos = Table[0, num + 1];
pos[[1]] = -h/2;
For[i = 2, i <= num + 1, i++, pos[[i]] = pos[[i - 1]] + t];

\[Xi]A = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]B = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]D = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, T0 = angles[[i, 1]];
  T1 = angles[[i, 2]];
  func[s_] := 
   Simplify@((2/d) (T1 - T0) Sqrt[(s - d/2)^2] + T0) (\[Pi]/180);
  theta[x_, y_] := alpha + func[x Cos[alpha] + y Sin[alpha]];
  zA = pos[[i + 1]] - pos[[i]];
  zB = pos[[i + 1]]^2 - pos[[i]]^2;
  zD = pos[[i + 1]]^3 - pos[[i]]^3;
  V1 = Cos[2 theta[x, y]]; V2 = Sin[2 theta[x, y]];
  V3 = Cos[4 theta[x, y]]; V4 = Sin[4 theta[x, y]];
  \[Xi]a = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zA;
  \[Xi]b = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zB;
  \[Xi]d = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zD;
  \[Xi]A = \[Xi]A + \[Xi]a;
  \[Xi]B = \[Xi]B + \[Xi]b;
  \[Xi]D = \[Xi]D + \[Xi]d;];
mU = {{U1, U2, 0, U3, 0}, {U4, 0, 0, -U3, 0}, {U1, -U2, 0, U3, 0}, {0,
     0, U2/2, 0, U3}, {0, 0, U2/2, 0, -U3}, {U5, 0, 0, -U3, 0}};

mA = mU.\[Xi]A; mB = (mU.\[Xi]B)/2; mD = (mU.\[Xi]D)/3;
A11[x_, y_] = mA[[1]]; A12[x_, y_] = mA[[2]]; A16[x_, y_] = mA[[4]];
A22[x_, y_] = mA[[3]]; A26[x_, y_] = mA[[5]]; A66[x_, y_] = mA[[6]];
D11[x_, y_] = mD[[1]]; D12[x_, y_] = mD[[2]]; D16[x_, y_] = mD[[4]];
D22[x_, y_] = mD[[3]]; D26[x_, y_] = mD[[5]]; D66[x_, y_] = mD[[6]];

Nx[x_, y_] = 
  A11[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A12[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A16[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);
Ny[x_, y_] = 
  A12[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A22[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A26[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

Nxy[x_, y_] = 
  A16[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A26[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A66[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

PDEs = {D[Nx[x, y], {x, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {y, 1}], 
   D[Ny[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {x, 1}]};

gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0}, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0}, y == b]};
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];

PDEs = FullSimplify[PDEs];

{U, V} = NDSolveValue[{PDEs == {0, 0}, gammaD, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == a/2]}, {u, 
    v}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

Plotting it the solution for U[x,y], it's possible to see two peaks.

[image: U[x,y] plot]

Differentiation of x (`D[U[x, y], {x, 1}]`) potentiates these peaks as can be seen bellow

[image: D[U[x,y],x]

These are not expected results. Would anyone know the reason of these peaks? I've been tried to refine the mesh (~ 10000 quad elements) and these peaks keep happening. Am I losing some important thing here?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use exact number since it turns symbolic calculation and probably force `LinearSolve` to get exact solution. Just put for instance `alpha = 45.001 (\[Pi]/180);` and then you get desirable result (I deleted line of code you repeat  twice with `omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];`)

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

G = 6.894745 10^9;

E1 = 26.25 G; E2 = 1.49 G; G12 = 
 1.04 G; nu12 = 0.28; nu21 = (E2*nu12)/E1;

t = 0.0050 .0254;
Son = {{1/E1, -nu12/E1, 0}, {-nu21/E2, 1/E2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/G12}}; Qon =
  Inverse[Son];

Q11 = Qon[[1, 1]]; Q12 = Qon[[1, 2]]; Q22 = Qon[[2, 2]]; Q66 = 
 Qon[[3, 3]];

U1 = (3 Q11 + 3 Q22 + 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8; U2 = (Q11 - Q22)/
  2; U3 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U4 = (Q11 + Q22 + 6 Q12 - 4 Q66)/
  8; U5 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2 Q12 + 4 Q66)/8;

alpha = 45.001 (\[Pi]/180);
a = 1; b = 1; d = a Cos[alpha] + b Sin[alpha];
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
u0 = 0.01;

angle1 = 10; angle0 = 0;
angles = {{angle0, angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
    angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, angle1}};

num = Dimensions[angles][[1]]; h = num*t; pos = Table[0, num + 1];
pos[[1]] = -h/2;
For[i = 2, i <= num + 1, i++, pos[[i]] = pos[[i - 1]] + t];

\[Xi]A = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]B = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
\[Xi]D = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, T0 = angles[[i, 1]];
  T1 = angles[[i, 2]];
  func[s_] := 
   Simplify@((2.0/d) (T1 - T0) Sqrt[(s - d/2)^2] + T0) (\[Pi]/180);
  theta[x_, y_] := alpha + func[x Cos[alpha] + y Sin[alpha]];
  zA = pos[[i + 1]] - pos[[i]]; zB = pos[[i + 1]]^2 - pos[[i]]^2;
  zD = pos[[i + 1]]^3 - pos[[i]]^3;
  V1 = Cos[2 theta[x, y]]; V2 = Sin[2 theta[x, y]];
  V3 = Cos[4 theta[x, y]]; V4 = Sin[4 theta[x, y]];
  \[Xi]a = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zA;
  \[Xi]b = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zB;
  \[Xi]d = {1, V1, V2, V3, V4} zD;
  \[Xi]A = \[Xi]A + \[Xi]a;
  \[Xi]B = \[Xi]B + \[Xi]b;
  \[Xi]D = \[Xi]D + \[Xi]d;];

mU = {{U1, U2, 0, U3, 0}, {U4, 0, 0, -U3, 0}, {U1, -U2, 0, U3, 0}, {0,
     0, U2/2, 0, U3}, {0, 0, U2/2, 0, -U3}, {U5, 0, 0, -U3, 0}};

mA = mU.\[Xi]A; mB = (mU.\[Xi]B)/2; mD = (mU.\[Xi]D)/3;

A11[x_, y_] = mA[[1]]; A12[x_, y_] = mA[[2]]; A16[x_, y_] = mA[[4]];
A22[x_, y_] = mA[[3]]; A26[x_, y_] = mA[[5]]; A66[x_, y_] = mA[[6]];
D11[x_, y_] = mD[[1]]; D12[x_, y_] = mD[[2]]; D16[x_, y_] = mD[[4]];
D22[x_, y_] = mD[[3]]; D26[x_, y_] = mD[[5]]; D66[x_, y_] = mD[[6]];

Nx[x_, y_] = 
  A11[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A12[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A16[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

Ny[x_, y_] = 
  A12[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A22[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A26[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

Nxy[x_, y_] = 
  A16[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A26[x, y] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
   A66[x, y] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

PDEs = {D[Nx[x, y], {x, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {y, 1}], 
   D[Ny[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {x, 1}]};



gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == 0],DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == b]};



        {U, V} = NDSolveValue[{PDEs == {0, 0}, gammaD, 
            Dirichlet

Condition[u[x, y] == 0, x == a/2]}, {u, 
        v}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

Visualisation

```
{DensityPlot[U[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 DensityPlot[V[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
If we change boundary condition as `gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0}, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0}, y == b]};`, then the solution looks as follows

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Alex, you used `gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == b]};`, instead `gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0}, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0, y == b]};`. My plots was created using the last one gammaD, as it's in my question. Did you see?

Comment: @DiegoMagela Thank you, I changed the code and figure. It looks the same.

Comment: Alex, sorry me for this, but in your code it is the same `gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == 0], DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0, u[x, y] == 0}, y == b]};`. The correct gammaD is `gammaD = {DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == u0}, y == 0], DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == -u0}, y == b]};`. Using your advice for alpha = 45.001 does not changed the peak for U[x,y]. Please, could you check again your code? Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoMagela Ok, I used a new `gammaD` and now can see small pick due to boundary condition `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == a/2]`

Comment: Alex, yes, exactly. But when you take the derivative of `U[x,y]`, being `diff[x_,y_] = D[U[x, y], x]` the peaks get very high. Do you see these behavior just due to BC?

Comment: @DiegoMagela Yes, it seems like this BC is wrong in your problem. I  don't understand how we can physically manage this BC.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, exact numbers will not and can not force an exact LinearSolve for FEM. It can not since we only have machine precision code anyways.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I think it is alright with BC. Running it for `alpha = 0` this not happen, but for `alpha = 1.0 (\[Pi]/180)` this peaks happens.

Comment: @user21, would be that a FEM package instability? Could you manage this?

Comment: @DiegoMagela For `alpha=0` there is symmetrical case, so BC is valid, but for $alpha \ne 0$ this BC is not true.

Comment: @user21 It is not first time I am getting this kind of error due to mixing of numerical and symbolic calculations. It is better to make all symbolic calculations separately and use final result with 'NDSolve[]'.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, what ever you have seen there is is not because LinearSolve uses exact numbers in FEM.